# istio v1.11.4 - install via helm chart; how to enable envoy proxy logging?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio

This is probably a very basic question. I am looking at [Install Istio with Helm](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/) and [Enable Envoy’s access logging](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#enable-envoy-s-access-logging).

How do I enable envoy access logging if I install istio via its helm charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest, and probably only, way to do this is to install Istio with IstioOperator using Helm.

Steps to do so are almost the same, but instead of `base` chart, you need to use `istio-operator` chart.

First create `istio-operator` namespace:

```text
kubectl create namespace istio-operator
```

then deploy IstioOperator using Helm *(assuming you have downloaded Istio, and changed current working directory to istio root)*:

```text
helm install istio-operator manifests/charts/istio-operator -n istio-operator
```

Having installed IstioOperator, you can now install Istio. This is a step where you can enable Envoy’s access logging:

```text
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: default
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
EOF
```

---

I tried enabling Envoy’s access logging with `base` chart, but could not succeed, no matter what I did.